Wondering the best written form of a (particular) "hmph!" utterance
Using references I was able to find a few possible forms for "hmph!" utterances, however, (in every language) there are a vast number of (very distinct) meanings or implications of "hmphs" - ranging from haughty disgust, serious approbation, thoughtful surprise, etc.
Fortunately I have a precise example of the "hmph!" variation in question, a famous scene from a famous anime:
https://www.reddit.com/r/HiScoreGirl/comments/1erc7ri/%E3%82%80%E3%81%A3/
(FWIW if you scroll down one post, you can see the English performance; and indeed as you know it of course doesn't sound at like HMF in Japanese, it's WHIEA or something; the ' むっ ! ' is a random guess and may be valueless, the wrong sound and/or meaning.)
Anyway, how would and in which form would you likely write the particular "hmph!" performed by the amazing Suzushiro there?

The "humph" sound made by the girl in the video is usually transcribed in Japanese as "ふん(っ)", although this ふ is not the normal /fu/. Meaning-wise, ふんっ indicates the speaker's disagreement or dissatisfaction, so there is no big difference between English and Japanese. That said, as seen in the video, ふんっ might be more commonly associated with childish or tsundere characters in Japanese.

ふんっ !  thank you so much!

With the braces, you're saying the  っ  is optional?  (Sorry if I misunderstood.)   ふんっ versus ふん ?  TY

@Fattie Yes, っ is optional, but it effectively works like an exclamation mark.

Thanks for your generous explanation  っ  !!

Using even more of your time, is this sort of thing ふんっっっっ seen, as one might damn!!!!! in English, or does the analogy with ! not really carry that far?  TY

@Fattie Can you elaborate? "Humph!" and "Damn!" are clearly different interjections in English, no?

sorry, my point was in English you often use "a few" exclamation points rather than just the one, to be funny.  Funny!!!  I was just wondering if っ is used the same way.  (I typed 'damn' only as a random unrelated example of a word, to follow with one or more exclamation points.)  TY

@Fattie Okay. We write something like ふんっっ！！！ for stronger exclamation. You can see something like this a lot in manga.

got it. Sorry to bother you.  Have a good one!  Bounty en route
